# Difference betweeb ionic and yeoman scaffolding

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a hybrid mobile application to be developed with the framework and IONIC AngularJS . I have not Started , I want to generate the structure of my application and I hesitate between IONIC GENERATOR native to the framework and Yeoman ionic generator  . Someone could find out about the differences between these two generators ? That brings the generator yeoman more compared to ionic generator ? Thanks